# Animation of circles on python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to get circles to appear one by one in random locations on a plot, with an interval of 1 second. If the circles overlap, the overlapping circles need to be added to clusters and change colours depending on which cluster they belong to, or if they touch the left or right side of the 'box'. I am new to python and am therefore struggling with this project. The clusters need to continue growing until there are 5 circles in a cluster. Therefore, I am struggling also to create a function that will continue to create circles until this condition is met.

Here is the code I have written so far

```
import numpy.random as nr
import scipy as sp
import pylab as plt 
import itertools
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

radius = 0.05
number_of_disks = 10
coordinates = nr.uniform(size=(number_of_disks, 2))
print coordinates

plt.close('all')  


fig = plt.figure()   
ax = plt.gca()

#plot of all disks
for coordinate in coordinates:

ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box') 
circle = plt.Circle((coordinate[0], coordinate[1]), radius, alpha = 0.4, color='b')
ax.add_artist(circle)

plt.show()

disks = []
overlapping_disks = []
disks_at_edge = []
clusters = {}

def touch_sides(disk, radius):
    for row in range(0, number_of_disks):
        x = coordinates[row, 0]
        y = coordinates[row, 1]
        left = True if x<= radius else False
        right = True if x>=1-radius else False
        disks.append({'x': x, 'y': y, 'left': left, 'right': right, 'cluster': 0})

def disk_overlap(disk, disk_after, radius):
    for disk, disk_after in itertools.combinations(coordinates,2):
        if sp.sqrt(sp.power(disk[0]-disk_after[0],2)+sp.power(disk[1]-disk_after[1],2)) < 2*radius:
            overlapping_disks.append((disk, disk_after))
```

Comment: what is the problem ? Do you get error message ? Show full message in question.

Comment: For the moment, the code seems to work as there are no error messages, but I am really unsure how to proceed with creating clusters

Comment: If distance between centers of circles is smaller than sum of its radius then they overlap. So you have to check new circle with every existing circle. If new circle doesn't overlap any circle then create new cluster with this circle only. If new circle overlaps existing circle then you have to add new circle to this cluster. if new circle overlap two existing circles then you will have to add one cluster to another.

Comment: How would I create this code that generates one circle at a time.

Comment: it adds one circle at a time to plot using `FuncAnimation` - http://pastebin.com/kmBAd18y

Comment: Little simpler - http://pastebin.com/yUhvSL1b